# How to edit this question?

Tags: discussion, editing

One of my questions  [Can firewall stop social engineering attacks?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/137394/can-firewall-stop-social-engineering-attacks) has been put on hold on the grounds of "too broad".
I have one concerns here.
1)  If I lack knowledge in a particular area, it will be difficult for me to be specific in the question. In this case, I found community effort valuable. After reading their answers and comments, I could direct myself in right direction and read more about the particular question.
So should it be put on hold considering the person who asked gained value and the community efforts helped him?

And if it is still needed to be edited, please tell me what are the some of the details should I add to the question?

Answer (score 3):

I personally voted to keep it open, but I can understand why others voted to close it as to broad. My guess (and I can be wrong here) is that the highlighted part here is the problem:

> Yes, a certain set of settings can help to detect at least some of the social engineering attacks, ***and they are***?

Taken literally, you are asking for all configurations of all possible different firewalls that could in any way help protect against social engineering. That is very broad indeed, but I don't think that is what you want to know.

Perhaps you could change it to this (which I think would be in line with the existing answers):

> Yes, a certain set of settings can help to detect at least some of the social engineering attacks. ***If so, what kind of attacks?***'

Instead of asking for the exact configuration, you ask about what group of attacks (e.g. phishing) you should look into. Then later, you can ask a more specific question about how to prevent it (e.g. "How do I configure my firewall of brand X to detect phishing attacks?").

That is at least my two cents. Others might not agree, and I can not guarantee that the question will be reopened if you make that change.

(You can still accept an answer if you want to, even though the question is closed, by the way. Not saying you should, that is up to you.)